# Word for being proud of oneself

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I was recently in a situation where I felt proud of myself for being in, but could not, for the life of me, think of a word for how I was feeling.

I want to give a name to the feeling, not just say I am feeling proud of myself. Like for example: "I feel accomplished", but it didn't quite fit. Basically, I guess you can say I am looking for a different word than proud.

What is the right word for feeling proud of oneself for being in a particular situation?

Comment: Satisfied, content, or gratified might work, but proud is the best.

Answer (score 0):

"Proud" *is* the right word.

There are several senses of "proud". It can mean "feeling happy about an event or situation" or "having an overly high opinion of oneself".  The first sense is positive, the second is negative.

You can "proud" in the first sense to describe your feeling.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a noun, use *pride*:

> a feeling of deep pleasure or satisfaction derived from one's own achievements, the achievements of those with whom one is closely associated, or from qualities or possessions that are widely admired. (NOAD)

For example, you could say your [heart swelled with pride](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/swell-with-pride-anger-etc) because of your recent promotion.

But in the sentence "I feel [blank]" you would need to use *proud*.